# Sharepoint Online : Lookup Field not visible on New/Edit Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I added 3 new lookup columns(optional) to one of the lists in the app web while upgrading my SharePoint Add-In.
But I can only see the labels for those 3 columns, the dropdowns are not visible either in NewForm or EditForm.

If I try to modify the item in quick edit mode, the dropdowns show below error.

> "Service Not Available".

Note that I'm able to modify other lookup columns which were added before the upgrade.
Moreover, when I try to fetch the list items from this list in my app through REST API, i get an error saying "

> Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes
>   (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

[image: ParentProject,ParentTask,ParentClient are the lookup columns that were added]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!